# How to determine the level sets of $f(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions

I need to determine the level sets of

$$f(x,y,z)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}, (x, y, z) \neq (0, 0, 0)$$

It's clear to me what do do if we have $f(x,y,z)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ but I don't understand what to do if we have a fraction. How to do it?

Comment: Try spherical coordinates.

Comment: What are the level sets of $g(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$? Circles. So by analogy...

Comment: @SimonS If we have $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$ then it's a sphere, right?

Comment: Yes, the level sets of that $f$ are spheres centered at the origin.

Comment: @SimonS But have a fraction. How to do it?

Comment: If $x^2 + y^2 = 1/c$, what's the radius of that circle?

Comment: @SimonS $\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{c}}$

Comment: Right ... that should answer your query of how to deal with the $f$ of your original post.

Comment: If $f(x,y,z) = c$ then

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} = c \ \ \Longrightarrow \ \ \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} = \frac{1}{c}$$
the equation of a sphere with radius $1/c$.

Comment: @SimonS OK Can you right it down as an answer? I wanna give you some points for the best answer!

Comment: It's ok. Thanks for the offer.

Comment: OK Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* $f(x,y,z)=c \iff \dfrac{1}{f(x,y,z)}=\dfrac{1}{c}, \ c \neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x,y,z)$ is the inverse of the distance to the origin.